# Fileinput stream / loading a simple txt file

Tags: java, android

Does anyone know why this crashes? All I'm doing is reading in a file in a txt file from my raw folder and when I click the load button in the other activity window, the code breaks when I call the variable testing within the file reader object upon click. log.d(null, ReadFileObject.fileText) Thanks in advance!

```
public class ReadFile extends Activity{
public String test;
public String testing;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
}
 public void fileText() {
    InputStream fis;
    fis =  getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.checkit);
    byte[] input;
    try {
        input = new byte [fis.available()];
        while(fis.read() != -1)
        {
            test += new String (input);
        }
        testing = test;
        fis.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
}

/* InputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.checkit);
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fis));
    String nextLine;
    int i = 0, j = 0;
    while ((nextLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
        if (j == 5) {
            j = 0;
            i++;
        }
       test += nextLine;
    }
} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
    System.out.println(e.getMessage());
} finally {
    if (fis != null) {
        try { fis.close(); }
        catch (IOException ignored) {}
    }
}*/

}
}
```

Comment: It's the indenting, android takes one look, and runs away.... :)

Comment: ha ha very funny. Do you guys have any suggestions? I'm new to android if you couldn't tell.

Comment: just did some coding and it looks like it's breaking in-between the input stream and the byte input.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is broken here:

```
byte[] input;
input = new byte [fis.available()];
while(fis.read() != -1) {
    test += new String (input);
}
testing = test;
fis.close();
```

In Java `available()` is unreliable [(read the Javadoc)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29).... and may even return 0. You should instead use a loop similar to:

```
InputStream fis = getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.checkit);
try {
    byte[] buffer = new byte[4096]; // 4K buffer
    int len = 0;
    while((len = fis.read(buffer)) != -1) {
        test += new String (buffer, 0, len);
    }
    testing = test;
} catch (IOException ioe) {
    ioe.printStackTrace();
    // make sure you do any other appropriate handling.
} finally {
    fis.close();
}
```

(although using string concatenation is probably not the best idea, use a StringBuilder).

Comment: Yeah, I'm addressing the crash, not the 100% correctness, thougj I will edit.

Comment: ok cool I'm making progress. It now says it is crashing at the fis object. I generated a new text file a renamed it and it's still crashing.. ughh.

Answer (score -1):

Your class extends `` `activity `` but theres nothing inside `oncreate`. If you need a simple `java` program try to create `New java Project` . Since you extend `activity` you should `setcontentview(yourLayout)`. Then call your `method` from oncreate and do your stuffs

Comment: I'm just calling this class by clicking the button, there's not really a need for a layout.. yet at least.

Comment: So remove the extend activity and oncreate from it. use it as a normal class, as you keep your code more complex it would be more difficult to debug